# How do I apply the string to specific rows

Tags: google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have the following Google Sheets formula:

=IF(COUNTIF(P3:P300,"Liverpool"),"North West","")

In my formula, for every row in column Town (column P) with the string "Liverpool", I want to put "North West" in Region (Column V). If "Liverpool" is not in column P, then leave column V blank. The problem is, the formula puts "North West" into every row.
So "North West" should only appear in rows 3 and 5

| Name | Town | Region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| School 1 | Salisbury | North West |
| School 2 | Leeds | North West |
| School 3 | Liverpool | North West |
| School 4 | Birmingham | North West |
| School 5 | Liverpool | North West |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SIMPLE SOLUTION:**
In cell `V2` enter:

```
=IF(P2="Liverpool","North West","")
```

Then drag it down the entire column.

**ADVANCED SOLUTION:**
If you want to avoid having to drag the formula down when the range gets larger you can enter the below in `V2` instead:

```
=BYROW(P2:P,
  LAMBDA(t,
    IF(t="Liverpool","North West"
      ,"")
  )
)
```

*NOTE: The line returns and indents are not necessary, just added to improve readability*